# Add event handler to element ID created within .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a web app I'm building that creates elements in a queue based on what was input into a form.  The HTML for these elements are generated by a "template" that has a couple icons in it that will be used as buttons once I can add my addEventHandler call, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.  My eventhandler should be called after the DOM has loaded, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here's my (basic) code:

```js
// Init app
let init = function() {

  // Set up user input handling
  submit.addEventListener('click', inputHandler); // TODO: Fix button 
  contentInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && contentInput.value != '') {
      e.preventDefault();
      inputHandler();
    }
  });

  let getFlag = document.getElementById('flag--LRI3LcUxQ9W5RfIWoc8');
  getFlag.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('IT WORKED');
  });

}

let renderQueryList = function() {
  // Determine which item to render (timestamp, number of views, flagged)    
  const oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;

  const arrLength = queue.length;

  queueDisplay.innerHTML = '';

  for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

    let element = queue[i];
    let whenAdded = element.age;

    if (!element.hasOwnProperty('type')) {
      element.type = 'text';
    }

    if ((now - whenAdded) > oneDay) {
      // console.log(element.text + ': this element is expired')
      return element.expired === true;
    }

    // TODO: check for type in templates, fallback to default type or display next item
    let singleElement = contentTypeTemplates[element.type](element);

    // for each item in list
    queueDisplay.appendChild(singleElement);
  }

}


// Set up templates
let contentTypeTemplates = {
  text: function(contentItem, index) {
    let container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'queueItem';
    container.setAttribute('id', contentItem.key);
    container.innerHTML = contentItem.text + '<div class="queueControls">' +
      '<i style="display: none;" class=" delete fas fa-times-circle" id="delete-' + contentItem.key + '"></i>' +
      '<i class="flag fas fa-flag" id="flag-' + contentItem.key + '"></i>' +
      '<i class="permanent fas fa-thumbtack" id="permanent-' + contentItem.key + '"></i>' +
      '</div>';
    return container;
  },
  image: function(contentItem) {

  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  init();
});
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53305416/edit), then click the snippet editor `[<>]` and create a [mcve] - you likely need to delegate your handlers

Comment: event delegation or you have to select the element after you add it.

Comment: Without knowing what "can't get it to work" actually means, I'd suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1):

After you do `container.innerHTML = 'html string'` you can use

```
container.querySelector('.someIconClass').addEventListener(eventName, handler)
```